# How to compare a list of rows to another list of rows in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out if there are any differences between a list of data with another. In order for a row of data to "match" with another row, the row must have the same values in their corresponding column. The rows themselves do not have to be in any particular order. In particular, I am dealing with a parts list, where there are part numbers, descriptions, etc. I am trying to figure out if any rows of data are different from rows of data from another list.

I found [Compare two sheets using arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007293/compare-two-sheets-using-arrays), which may have the answer to my problem, but I am having trouble figuring out how to adapt to my code due to inexperience in Visual Basic.

I was able to get it to work for a single column of data, comparing one column of data from one sheet to another, but cannot get it to compare entire rows of data.

Here is an example of I want this to work:

```
                   Sheet 1                                       Sheet 2
            Column 1       Column 2                      Column 1        Column 2

 Row 1         22a            33                            11              11

 Row 2         22a            33a                           22a             33

 Row 3         55            22b                            55              23b
```

The code in the link will tell you what is not in sheet 1 but in sheet 2 and vice versa. In this example, I would like the code to tell me Sheet 1 Row 2 and Sheet 1 Row 3 are not in Sheet 2, and Sheet 2 Row 1 and Sheet 2 Row 3 are not in Sheet 1 (Sheet 1 Row 1 and Sheet 2 Row 2 match).

Comment: I have posted 2 solutions below. One is not using VBA, the other is a simple work around using the code in the example.

In order to make this work by altering the code to check paired rows, I THINK you would have to use the code in the question, not in the accepted answer. The accepted answer uses Match, whitch I believe need to reference an actual excel range. If you use the answer question code, it will run slow on a large data set (as will my formula solution), but it is possible to alter it to work with column pairs. I must do that another day though, if you really need it.

Comment: And if you are satisfied, remember to mark as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is ok by you, you can do it without VBA using the following formula:

```
={IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1&"|"&B1;Sheet7!$A$1:$A$3&"|"&Sheet7!$B$1:$B$3;0);-1)=-1;"Unique";"")}
```

Assuming that each of your tables start in A1 (so that the tables with three entries span A1:B3), and entering this formula into C1 (and copying it down), press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when entering the formula to create an array formula, this will show the word "Unique" in column C if the pair in that row on that sheet is not in any of the row-pairs on sheet 2.

You can then use conditional formatting to highlight unique rows, filter on the tables to include only unique rows, or some other way of doing what you need.

NOTE 1: I have entered my numbers in Sheet6 and Sheet7 instead of 1 and 2. The formula written above goes into Sheet6.

NOTE 2: My language use ; instead of , as function separator, so if yours use , you need to change that.

NOTE 3: You will need to expand the ranges Sheet7!$A$1:$A$3 and Sheet7!$B$1:$B$3 if your set grows (this will happen automatically if new rows are inserted in between the old ones). The best is still probably to create named ranges for each of the 4 columns, exchange the references with those, and manage the named ranges instead of the formulas.

NOTE 4: If your data set contains the character "|", you need to change that as well, to match some character that you for sure do not have there.

---

Alternatively you could in column C on each cheet enter (assuming first entry in C1)

```
=A1&"|"&B1"
```

and copy this down, then run the solution from your copied example using that C column instead of on A1 and B1.

Comment: I hope @gudal will allow me to amend this fine formula answer (+1) so that the two outputs read as requested in the OP. Replace `"unique", "")` with `"Not in sheet 2","Matches sheet 2, row "&MATCH(A1&"|"&B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3&"|"&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,0))` Again remember to press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`