# Defining terms for an array search

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've been searching for an answer to this, but I haven't been able to find anything specific enough to fill the gap in my VBA knowledge.

I'm putting two lists of data into arrays to be compared using a modified version of the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007293/compare-two-sheets-using-arrays)
(I'll post it below).

HOWEVER, I don't want to input the whole cell into the array to be compared with the second array. For instance, if the cell in the first sheet says "Company, LLC", I would like to only search "Company". I have some code that does this:

```
 s = rCell.Value
    indexofthey = InStr(1, s, ",")
    aftercomma = Right(s, Len(s) - indexofthey + 1)
    celld = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(aftercomma))
```

The code I need to somehow work this into (copied from the answer to the question I linked above) is this:

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCompare2to1_Click()

Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet, sheet3 As Worksheet
Dim lngLastR As Long, lngCnt As Long
Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant, x
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range


Set sheet1 = Worksheets(1)
Set sheet2 = Worksheets(2)
Set sheet3 = Worksheets(3) ' assumes sheet3 is a blank sheet in your workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'let's get everything all set up
'sheet3 column headers
sheet3.Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("in1Not2", "in2Not1")

'sheet1 range and fill array
With sheet1

    lngLastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A" & lngLastR)
    var1 = rng1

End With

'sheet2 range and fill array
With sheet2

    lngLastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng2 = .Range("A1:A" & lngLastR)
    var2 = rng2

End With

'first check sheet1 against sheet2
On Error GoTo NoMatch1
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(var1)

    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(var1(lngCnt, 1), rng2, False)

Next


'now check sheet2 against sheet1
On Error GoTo NoMatch2
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(var2)

    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(var2(lngCnt, 1), rng1, False)

Next

On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

NoMatch1:
    sheet3.Range("A" & sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = var1(lngCnt, 1)
    Resume Next


NoMatch2:
    sheet3.Range("B" & sheet3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = var2(lngCnt, 1)
    Resume Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to change the values in your cells you will need to loop through the arrays. You can use a proc like this:

```
Sub RemoveUnwantedText(ByRef theArray As Variant)

Dim theValue As String
Dim i As Long
Dim indexOfComma As Integer
    ' array is created from single-column range of cells
    ' and so has 2 dimensions
    For i = LBound(theArray, 1) To UBound(theArray, 1)
        theValue = CStr(theArray(i, 1))
        indexOfComma = InStr(1, theValue, ",")
        If indexOfComma > 0 Then
            theValue = Trim(Left(theValue, indexOfComma - 1))
        End If
        theArray(i, 1) = theValue
    Next i

End Sub
```

Paste this into the same module as your code. In your code, before you do any comparison, add these calls:

```
RemoveUnwantedText var1
RemoveUnwantedText var2
```

Comment: I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error on the `theValue = CStr(theArray(i))` line

Comment: Can you double-check you've not made any typos? It worked fine for me. One second...

Comment: I've changed the code. Had not spotted that the array was populated straight from a one-column range of cells.