# Compare two workbooks - delete rows where match - add value from wkb 2 to wkb 1 where difference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compare

hope you can help me getting the different bits together.

I have two workbooks, wkbPB (foundation), wkbZLISTP (to be compared with wkbPB).
Both workbooks have two columns containing article no. and list price.
I need to compare the list price of each article no. in wkbPB with the list price of that article no. in wkbZLISTP.

- Where there is a match in article no. and the list price difference is less than 0.04 delete the row in wkbPB.
- Where there is a match in article no. and the list price difference is greater than 0.04 the list price of wkbZLISTP needs to be written in the column beside the list price in wkbPB.
- Where there is no match in article no., "MISSING" is written into that additional column beside the list price in wkbPB in red.

Currently I am working this task with a For Next loop that holds a find dialog. It does the trick, but it takes up to 45min to finish.
Now I've searched the internet and came across a comparison via array which seems to be lightning fast. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007293/compare-two-sheets-using-arrays).

However, I can't stick together how to customize that code for my purpose, total brain freeze.
Can you help?

Thx a lot!

```
Dim d As Long
For d = 2 To noOfRowsPB Step 1
    If wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Dim looking4 As String
        looking4 = UCase(wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d, 26).Value)
        Dim ctrUPNRng As Range
        Dim ctrUPNRow As Long
        Set ctrUPNRng = wkbZLISTP.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(looking4, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not ctrUPNRng Is Nothing Then
            ctrUPNRow = ctrUPNRng.Row
            If Abs(CSng(wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d, 24).Value) - CSng(wkbZLISTP.Worksheets(1).Cells(ctrUPNRow, 14).Value)) > 0.04 Then
                wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d, 27).Value = wkbZLISTP.Worksheets(1).Cells(ctrUPNRow, 14).Value
            Else
                 Rows(d).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                 d = d - 1
            End If
        Else
            wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d, 27).Value = "MISSING"
            With wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Range("AA" & d).Font
                .Color = -16776961
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next d
```

Answer (score 0):

it took a while, but I've managed to get it working on my own!

All that I needed was to get the right picture of an array into my head! And that is actually pretty simple: An array is nothing else than a table. So you get the range of data from your worksheet and you assign that range to an array! Done!

Well, couple of challenges still to overcome, but with that basic understanding I got it working!

And look at the time savings: OLD macro: 33:43 min, NEW macro: 7:31 min!

And this is how it looks like now:

```
Dim d As Long
Dim PBArray As Variant
Dim ZLISTPArray As Variant
Dim f As Long
Dim rngPB As Range
Dim rngZLISTP As Range
Dim rowDel As Long
noOfRowsPB = wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
noOfRowsZLISTP = wkbZLISTP.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngPB = wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(noOfRowsPB, 26))
PBArray = rngPB
wkbZLISTP.Activate
Set rngZLISTP = wkbZLISTP.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(noOfRowsZLISTP, 19))
ZLISTPArray = rngZLISTP

rowDel = 0
For d = 1 To UBound(PBArray)
    For f = 1 To UBound(ZLISTPArray)
        'Can we find it?
        If PBArray(d, 26) = ZLISTPArray(f, 19) Then
            'Found it, now price comparison
            If Abs(PBArray(d, 24) - ZLISTPArray(f, 14)) > 0.04 Then
               'Price difference, we want to see it
               wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d + 1 - rowDel, 27).Value = wkbZLISTP.Worksheets(1).Cells(f + 1, 14).Value
               Exit For
            Else
                'No price difference, we can delete it
                wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Rows(d + 1 - rowDel).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                rowDel = rowDel + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        ElseIf f = UBound(ZLISTPArray) Then
            'Despite searching to the end, no findings, then we need to make that visible too
            wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Cells(d + 1 - rowDel, 27).Value = "MISSING"
            With wkbPB.Worksheets(1).Range("AA" & d + 1 - rowDel).Font
                .Color = -16776961
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next f
Next d
```

Maybe this will help somebody too one day!

ENJOY!